# Custom CheckBoxPreference, how to disable title and summary from clicking

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferences, preferenceactivity

I hate the regular CheckBoxPreference because you can click anywhere on the preference and toggle the value.  I'm trying to create a custom CheckBoxPreference where I can allow ONLY the checkbox to be clicked, and ignore the title or summary.  However, I can't seem to figure this out.

My custom CheckBoxPreference looks like the standard form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/talkButtonText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+android:id/title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#c0c0c0"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+android:id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Currently, this functions exactly like the standard CheckBoxPreference, where clicking anywhere on the entire width changes the check box value.  Is there any simply way to disable the title and summary from being clicked?

Comment: that code should work, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't want to be able to click the summary/title, but ONLY the checkbox.  It's too easy to accidentally select a preference when you can hit the entire area.

Comment: could you put your activity or fragment class?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the clickable/focusable=false from the check box and add it to the linear layout.

Comment: When I do that, the check box doesn't link to the preference anymore (so the preference isn't automatically saved).  When clickable/focusable is on the checkbox only it does save, but of course the entire text title/summary is clickable too.